# how to change style for selectedvalue in categoryfilter on Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

As in this picture

[image]

the selected value of categoryfilter on Google Chart looks bad,

the x should be on the right of value text and should have a bg color box 
to make it look better

how can I set the style for this?

***Runable code snippet***

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'controls']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);



function drawRegionsMap() {

  var query1 = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOyYwL51uWTd7Pv4Sp_bKdxWmH-g6QA2SDHhw93_2s8/edit?usp=sharing");
  //all
  query1.setQuery('select * where J="Take back policy model" order by F,Y,M,N,L');
  query1.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response1) {

  var data1 = response1.getDataTable();

  //set year that<2000 to 2000
  for (i = 0; i < data1.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

    var startdate = new Date(data1.getValue(i, 12));


    var y = startdate.getFullYear();



    if (y < 2000) {

      r = data1.getValue(i, 12);

      //console.log(i);

      startdate.setFullYear(2000);

      data1.setValue(i, 12, startdate);



    }

  }

  //set start date to previous row end date - groupByRowLabel

  for (var row = 1; row < data1.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {

    if (data1.getValue(row - 1, 5) == data1.getValue(row, 5) && data1.getValue(row - 1, 6) == data1.getValue(row, 6)) { //if the previous one has the same label   

      if (data1.getValue(row - 1, 13) > data1.getValue(row, 12)) { // if the previous end date is greater than the start date of current row
        data1.setValue(row - 1, 13, data1.getValue(row, 12)) // set the previous end date to the start date of current row
      }
    }
  }







  var view1 = new google.visualization.DataView(data1);
  view1.setColumns([
    //index column 0
    {
      type: 'string',
      id: 'Country',
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        //return countryname statename - policies // USA New York - WEEE
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 5) + " " + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 22) + " - " + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6)
      }
    },
    //index column 1

    {
      type: 'string',
      id: 'region',
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 8)
      }
    }
    //index column 2
    , {
      type: 'string',
      role: 'tooltip',
      properties: {
        html: true
      },
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        var country = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 5)
        var policy = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6)
        var dataname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 8)
        var dropname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 11)
        var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
          pattern: "MMMM yyyy"
        });
        var startdate = formatter.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 12));
        //var startdate = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 12)
        var comment = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 15)
        //colorValues.push(dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6))
        return '<br><div id="country">' + country + " - " + policy + '<br><br></div> ' +
          '<div id="header1">Dominant (E)PR policy model:<br></div>' +
          '<div id="dropname">' + dropname + '<br><br></div>' +
          '<div id ="header2">Since :&nbsp;</div><div id="date">' + startdate + " " + 'to current</div><br><br><br>' +
          '<div id ="comment">' + comment + '<\/div>'
      }
    },
    //style role
    {
      type: 'string',
      id: 'color',
      role: 'style',
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 25)
      }
    },


    //index column 3,4 start-enddate
    12, 13,

  ]);



  var chart1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Timeline',
    //dataTable: 'data1',
    containerId: 'colormap1',
    options: {
      width: 870,
      height: 800,
      //colors: colorValues,

      timeline: {
        groupByRowLabel: true,
        rowLabelStyle: {
          fontSize: 14,
          width: 800,

        },
        showBarLabels: false
      },
      hAxis: {
        minValue: new Date(2010, 0, 0),
        maxValue: new Date(2017, 0, 0)
      },
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      },
    }


  });


  var namePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': '1',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'caption': 'Choose a Region',
        'cssClass': 'filter',
        'selectedValuesLayout': 'aside',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': true
      }
    }
  });


  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));




  // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
  // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
  // given the chosen slider range.
  dashboard.bind(namePicker, chart1);
  // Draw the dashboard.
  dashboard.draw(view1);


  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'ready', function() {
    var svgParent = colormap1.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

    svgParent.parentNode.style.top = '40px';

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(colormap1.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(text) {
      if ((text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') &&
        (parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) < 200)) {
        text.setAttribute("x", "5");
        text.setAttribute("text-anchor", "start");
      }


      if ((text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') && (parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) < 850)) {

        var groupLabel = text.cloneNode(true);
        groupLabel.setAttribute('x', '850');
        groupLabel.innerHTML = '2017';
        groupLabel.setAttribute('y', '971.05');
        groupLabel.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial');
        groupLabel.setAttribute('font-size', '13');
        svgParent.appendChild(groupLabel);



      }


    })



  })
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'select', tableSelectHandler);


  function tableSelectHandler() {
    var selection = chart1.getChart().getSelection()[0];
    var chartDataView = chart1.getDataTable();
    var rowindex = chartDataView.getTableRowIndex(selection.row);
    var cnid = data1.getValue(rowindex, 0);
    var polid = data1.getValue(rowindex, 1);
    var strid = data1.getValue(rowindex, 2);
    //var sid = (strid) - 1;

    var statecode = data1.getValue(rowindex, 4);

    //if (selection.length > 0) {
    //http://www.sagisepr.com/country.php?country=21&polsel=1&sid=17&statecode=AR
    window.open("http://www.sagisepr.com/country.php?country=" + cnid + "&polsel=" + polid + "&sid=" + strid + "&statecode=" + statecode);
    //}
  }
  google.visualization.events.addListener(namePicker, 'statechange', hidediv);

  function hidediv() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#:0.goog-menuitem goog-option goog-menuitem-highlight").change(function(event) {
        document.getElementById('2000').hide();
        document.getElementById('2010').hide();
        document.getElementById('2017').hide();

      });
      $("#:4.goog-menuitem goog-option goog-menuitem-highlight").change(function(event) {
        document.getElementById('2000').hide();
        document.getElementById('2010').hide();
        document.getElementById('2017').hide();

      });
    })
  }


}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">

  <div id="2000" style="z-index:1;position: fixed;top: 70px;left: 168px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13;color:red;">2000</div>

  <div id="2010" style="z-index:1;position: fixed;top: 70px;left: 556px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13;color:red;">2010</div>

  <div id="2017" style="z-index:1;position: fixed;top: 70px;left: 850px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13;color:red;">2017</div>


  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <!--chart_div!-->
  <div id='colormap1' style="position:fixed;">

  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please show some code.

Comment: @wayneOS already edited,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the class name given to the option --> `ui.cssClass`
will be given to the category filter element

use the class name provided to the option,
to style the elements of the filter

inspect the elements created by the filter to find which classes you want to style

```
// option
'cssClass': 'filter'

/* css */
.filter .google-visualization-controls-categoryfilter-selected li {
  background-color: #e65100;
  border: 1px solid #ff9800;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 6px;
}

.filter .goog-link-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'controls']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);



function drawRegionsMap() {

  var query1 = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOyYwL51uWTd7Pv4Sp_bKdxWmH-g6QA2SDHhw93_2s8/edit?usp=sharing");
  //all
  query1.setQuery('select * where J="Take back policy model" order by F,Y,M,N,L');
  query1.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response1) {

  var data1 = response1.getDataTable();

  //set year that<2000 to 2000
  for (i = 0; i < data1.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

    var startdate = new Date(data1.getValue(i, 12));


    var y = startdate.getFullYear();



    if (y < 2000) {

      r = data1.getValue(i, 12);

      //console.log(i);

      startdate.setFullYear(2000);

      data1.setValue(i, 12, startdate);



    }

  }

  //set start date to previous row end date - groupByRowLabel

  for (var row = 1; row < data1.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {

    if (data1.getValue(row - 1, 5) == data1.getValue(row, 5) && data1.getValue(row - 1, 6) == data1.getValue(row, 6)) { //if the previous one has the same label   

      if (data1.getValue(row - 1, 13) > data1.getValue(row, 12)) { // if the previous end date is greater than the start date of current row
        data1.setValue(row - 1, 13, data1.getValue(row, 12)) // set the previous end date to the start date of current row
      }
    }
  }







  var view1 = new google.visualization.DataView(data1);
  view1.setColumns([
    //index column 0
    {
      type: 'string',
      id: 'Country',
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        //return countryname statename - policies // USA New York - WEEE
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 5) + " " + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 22) + " - " + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6)
      }
    },
    //index column 1

    {
      type: 'string',
      id: 'region',
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 8)
      }
    }
    //index column 2
    , {
      type: 'string',
      role: 'tooltip',
      properties: {
        html: true
      },
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        var country = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 5)
        var policy = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6)
        var dataname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 8)
        var dropname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 11)
        var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
          pattern: "MMMM yyyy"
        });
        var startdate = formatter.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 12));
        //var startdate = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 12)
        var comment = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 15)
        //colorValues.push(dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6))
        return '<br><div id="country">' + country + " - " + policy + '<br><br></div> ' +
          '<div id="header1">Dominant (E)PR policy model:<br></div>' +
          '<div id="dropname">' + dropname + '<br><br></div>' +
          '<div id ="header2">Since :&nbsp;</div><div id="date">' + startdate + " " + 'to current</div><br><br><br>' +
          '<div id ="comment">' + comment + '<\/div>'
      }
    },
    //style role
    {
      type: 'string',
      id: 'color',
      role: 'style',
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 25)
      }
    },


    //index column 3,4 start-enddate
    12, 13,

  ]);



  var chart1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Timeline',
    //dataTable: 'data1',
    containerId: 'colormap1',
    options: {
      width: 870,
      height: 800,
      //colors: colorValues,

      timeline: {
        groupByRowLabel: true,
        rowLabelStyle: {
          fontSize: 14,
          width: 800,

        },
        showBarLabels: false
      },
      hAxis: {
        minValue: new Date(2010, 0, 0),
        maxValue: new Date(2017, 0, 0)
      },
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      },
    }


  });


  var namePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': '1',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'caption': 'Choose a Region',
        'cssClass': 'filter',
        'selectedValuesLayout': 'aside',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': true
      }
    }
  });


  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));




  // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
  // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
  // given the chosen slider range.
  dashboard.bind(namePicker, chart1);
  // Draw the dashboard.
  dashboard.draw(view1);


  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'ready', function() {
    var svgParent = colormap1.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

    svgParent.parentNode.style.top = '40px';

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(colormap1.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(text) {
      if ((text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') &&
        (parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) < 200)) {
        text.setAttribute("x", "5");
        text.setAttribute("text-anchor", "start");
      }


      if ((text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') && (parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) < 850)) {

        var groupLabel = text.cloneNode(true);
        groupLabel.setAttribute('x', '850');
        groupLabel.innerHTML = '2017';
        groupLabel.setAttribute('y', '971.05');
        groupLabel.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial');
        groupLabel.setAttribute('font-size', '13');
        svgParent.appendChild(groupLabel);



      }


    })



  })
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'select', tableSelectHandler);


  function tableSelectHandler() {
    var selection = chart1.getChart().getSelection()[0];
    var chartDataView = chart1.getDataTable();
    var rowindex = chartDataView.getTableRowIndex(selection.row);
    var cnid = data1.getValue(rowindex, 0);
    var polid = data1.getValue(rowindex, 1);
    var strid = data1.getValue(rowindex, 2);
    //var sid = (strid) - 1;

    var statecode = data1.getValue(rowindex, 4);

    //if (selection.length > 0) {
    //http://www.sagisepr.com/country.php?country=21&polsel=1&sid=17&statecode=AR
    window.open("http://www.sagisepr.com/country.php?country=" + cnid + "&polsel=" + polid + "&sid=" + strid + "&statecode=" + statecode);
    //}
  }
  google.visualization.events.addListener(namePicker, 'statechange', hidediv);

  function hidediv() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#:0.goog-menuitem goog-option goog-menuitem-highlight").change(function(event) {
        document.getElementById('2000').hide();
        document.getElementById('2010').hide();
        document.getElementById('2017').hide();

      });
      $("#:4.goog-menuitem goog-option goog-menuitem-highlight").change(function(event) {
        document.getElementById('2000').hide();
        document.getElementById('2010').hide();
        document.getElementById('2017').hide();

      });
    })
  }


}
```

```css
.filter .google-visualization-controls-categoryfilter-selected li {
  background-color: #e65100;
  border: 1px solid #ff9800;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 6px;
}

.filter .goog-link-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">

  <div id="2000" style="z-index:1;position: fixed;top: 70px;left: 168px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13;color:red;">2000</div>

  <div id="2010" style="z-index:1;position: fixed;top: 70px;left: 556px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13;color:red;">2010</div>

  <div id="2017" style="z-index:1;position: fixed;top: 70px;left: 850px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13;color:red;">2017</div>


  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <!--chart_div!-->
  <div id='colormap1' style="position:fixed;">

  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

remove the option to use the default styles...

```
'cssClass': 'filter'
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'controls']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);



function drawRegionsMap() {

  var query1 = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOyYwL51uWTd7Pv4Sp_bKdxWmH-g6QA2SDHhw93_2s8/edit?usp=sharing");
  //all
  query1.setQuery('select * where J="Take back policy model" order by F,Y,M,N,L');
  query1.send(drawDashboard);
}

function drawDashboard(response1) {

  var data1 = response1.getDataTable();

  //set year that<2000 to 2000
  for (i = 0; i < data1.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {

    var startdate = new Date(data1.getValue(i, 12));


    var y = startdate.getFullYear();



    if (y < 2000) {

      r = data1.getValue(i, 12);

      //console.log(i);

      startdate.setFullYear(2000);

      data1.setValue(i, 12, startdate);



    }

  }

  //set start date to previous row end date - groupByRowLabel

  for (var row = 1; row < data1.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {

    if (data1.getValue(row - 1, 5) == data1.getValue(row, 5) && data1.getValue(row - 1, 6) == data1.getValue(row, 6)) { //if the previous one has the same label   

      if (data1.getValue(row - 1, 13) > data1.getValue(row, 12)) { // if the previous end date is greater than the start date of current row
        data1.setValue(row - 1, 13, data1.getValue(row, 12)) // set the previous end date to the start date of current row
      }
    }
  }







  var view1 = new google.visualization.DataView(data1);
  view1.setColumns([
    //index column 0
    {
      type: 'string',
      id: 'Country',
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        //return countryname statename - policies // USA New York - WEEE
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 5) + " " + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 22) + " - " + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6)
      }
    },
    //index column 1

    {
      type: 'string',
      id: 'region',
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 8)
      }
    }
    //index column 2
    , {
      type: 'string',
      role: 'tooltip',
      properties: {
        html: true
      },
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        var country = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 5)
        var policy = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6)
        var dataname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 8)
        var dropname = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 11)
        var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
          pattern: "MMMM yyyy"
        });
        var startdate = formatter.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 12));
        //var startdate = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 12)
        var comment = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 15)
        //colorValues.push(dt.getFormattedValue(row, 6))
        return '<br><div id="country">' + country + " - " + policy + '<br><br></div> ' +
          '<div id="header1">Dominant (E)PR policy model:<br></div>' +
          '<div id="dropname">' + dropname + '<br><br></div>' +
          '<div id ="header2">Since :&nbsp;</div><div id="date">' + startdate + " " + 'to current</div><br><br><br>' +
          '<div id ="comment">' + comment + '<\/div>'
      }
    },
    //style role
    {
      type: 'string',
      id: 'color',
      role: 'style',
      calc: function(dt, row) {
        return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 25)
      }
    },


    //index column 3,4 start-enddate
    12, 13,

  ]);



  var chart1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Timeline',
    //dataTable: 'data1',
    containerId: 'colormap1',
    options: {
      width: 870,
      height: 800,
      //colors: colorValues,

      timeline: {
        groupByRowLabel: true,
        rowLabelStyle: {
          fontSize: 14,
          width: 800,

        },
        showBarLabels: false
      },
      hAxis: {
        minValue: new Date(2010, 0, 0),
        maxValue: new Date(2017, 0, 0)
      },
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      },
    }


  });


  var namePicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': '1',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'caption': 'Choose a Region',
        'selectedValuesLayout': 'aside',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': true
      }
    }
  });


  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));




  // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
  // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
  // given the chosen slider range.
  dashboard.bind(namePicker, chart1);
  // Draw the dashboard.
  dashboard.draw(view1);


  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'ready', function() {
    var svgParent = colormap1.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

    svgParent.parentNode.style.top = '40px';

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(colormap1.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(text) {
      if ((text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') &&
        (parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) < 200)) {
        text.setAttribute("x", "5");
        text.setAttribute("text-anchor", "start");
      }


      if ((text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') && (parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) < 850)) {

        var groupLabel = text.cloneNode(true);
        groupLabel.setAttribute('x', '850');
        groupLabel.innerHTML = '2017';
        groupLabel.setAttribute('y', '971.05');
        groupLabel.setAttribute('font-family', 'Arial');
        groupLabel.setAttribute('font-size', '13');
        svgParent.appendChild(groupLabel);



      }


    })



  })
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'select', tableSelectHandler);


  function tableSelectHandler() {
    var selection = chart1.getChart().getSelection()[0];
    var chartDataView = chart1.getDataTable();
    var rowindex = chartDataView.getTableRowIndex(selection.row);
    var cnid = data1.getValue(rowindex, 0);
    var polid = data1.getValue(rowindex, 1);
    var strid = data1.getValue(rowindex, 2);
    //var sid = (strid) - 1;

    var statecode = data1.getValue(rowindex, 4);

    //if (selection.length > 0) {
    //http://www.sagisepr.com/country.php?country=21&polsel=1&sid=17&statecode=AR
    window.open("http://www.sagisepr.com/country.php?country=" + cnid + "&polsel=" + polid + "&sid=" + strid + "&statecode=" + statecode);
    //}
  }
  google.visualization.events.addListener(namePicker, 'statechange', hidediv);

  function hidediv() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#:0.goog-menuitem goog-option goog-menuitem-highlight").change(function(event) {
        document.getElementById('2000').hide();
        document.getElementById('2010').hide();
        document.getElementById('2017').hide();

      });
      $("#:4.goog-menuitem goog-option goog-menuitem-highlight").change(function(event) {
        document.getElementById('2000').hide();
        document.getElementById('2010').hide();
        document.getElementById('2017').hide();

      });
    })
  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">

  <div id="2000" style="z-index:1;position: fixed;top: 70px;left: 168px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13;color:red;">2000</div>

  <div id="2010" style="z-index:1;position: fixed;top: 70px;left: 556px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13;color:red;">2010</div>

  <div id="2017" style="z-index:1;position: fixed;top: 70px;left: 850px;font-family: Arial;font-size: 13;color:red;">2017</div>


  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <!--chart_div!-->
  <div id='colormap1' style="position:fixed;">

  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```